# Bootstrap Tabs - detect second level active tab for breadcrumb visibility

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to to build a multi level bootstrap tabs with breadcrumbs above it.
The idea is to expand breadcumbs as you go through tabs1 to 3. That works.
And then I would like to hide last breadcrumb element once you go from fully expanded multi tabs to new tab, where there is no expanded tabs yet.

The code for breadcrumbs is:

```
<ul id="catLevelBreadcrumbs">
<li role="presentation" class="active breadElement breadElementL1">
<span>Step 1</span></li>
<ul id="catLevelBreadcrumbsInner">
<li role="presentation" class="breadElement breadElementL2 showBreadL2">
<span>Step 2</span></li>
<li role="presentation" class="breadElement breadElementL3 showBreadL3">
<span>Step 3</span></li>
</ul>
</ul>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pF1FZ.png)

And then there is multi tabs
- cat1L
  - cat2L
    -cat3L

```
<ul id="catLevel1" class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
<li class="kat1-tab-0-faq active"></li>
<li class="kat1-tab-1-faq"></li>
</ul>
<div id="contentLevel1">
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="first-cat-faq"></div>
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade active in" id="second-cat-faq">
<ul id="catLevel2" class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
<li class="kat2-tab-0-faq active"></li>
<li class="kat2-tab-1-faq"></li>
</ul>
<div id="contentLevel2">
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade active in" id="first-cat-faq-l2"></div>
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="second-cat-faq-l2"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RcByE.png)

I am trying to solve it with such js code, but It fails to do what I planned.

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '#catLevel1.nav-tabs > li' ,function(e){
$this = jQuery(this);
if(!$this.parent().next().find('#catLevel2 > li.active').hasClass('active')) 
{
console.log('is active');
jQuery('.breadElement.breadElementL3').removeClass('showBreadL3');
}
});
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to removeClass('showBreadL3') to last breadcrumb element when, you go from fully expanded tabs (cat1 -  cat2 - cat3) to tab1 (cat1) but only when there is no #catLevel2 > li.active on the second level (cat1 - cat2).
As Bootstrap tabs expansion is remembered once you go though them, I want to keep breadcrumbs expanded as well. What I dont't want is breadcrumbs expanded on tab (cat1) without (cat2 and cat3) expanded.

Comment: What I have noticed is that $this.parent().next().find('#catLevel2 > li').hasClass('active') does the job of targeting what I want, but it does that for all tabs and not the one I clicked and its child. Which gives true to all clicks and not to clicked tab.